# How do I pull values from another branch onto my local branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am new to git and I am running into the following issue- I created a branch 'Test' from develop. I am trying to pull changes from branch 'Working' (which is also based on develop) onto my local branch. I don't want any of my changes to affect develop or 'Working'.
How would I do this?

I am not sure whether this is a merge or a rebase.

Comment: It would be a merge `Working > Test`. First checkout the *destination* branch, the one *receiving* changes, so your branch Test. Then merge the *source* branch, with `git merge Working` (be sure you do have a local version of this branch. If not, either pull it or merge the remote ref, which could be `origin/Working` depending on your remote setting)

Answer (score 1):

Either will work, but the result is different.

- `git merge working` will create a single, new *merge commit* which combines the history of both branches. The commits are shared by both branches.
- `git rebase test working^{commit} && git push . HEAD:test && git checkout test` will rebase, i.e. *copy*, the commits on `working` to `test`. The commits are now duplicated and separate versions of the commits exist in both branches.

The third option is to cherry-pick, which is similar to rebase, but switches source and destination.

- `git cherry-pick test..working` will cherry-pick, i.e. *copy*, the commits on `working` and apply them to your test branch. The commits are duplicated and separate in both branches.

History after merge:

```
      D-E         -- working
     /   \
A-B-C     \       -- development
   \       \
    F-G-----M     -- test (M = merge commit)
```

History after rebase or cherry-pick:

```
      D-E         -- working
     /
A-B-C             -- development
   \    
    F-G-C'-D'-E'  -- test (C', D', E' = copied commits)
```